# Heroku "We're sorry, but something went wrong" for a simple rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

This is my first time using Heroku, so I don`t really know what the errors mean.   I basically used rails and bootstrap to create a site (with just links, no dynamic features).

```
 ←[36m2013-04-17T21:47:59.413491+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
 ←[36m2013-04-17T21:47:59.413491+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   from script/rails:6:in `require'
 ←[36m2013-04-17T21:47:59.413491+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
 ←[36m2013-04-17T21:47:59.413199+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:59:in `start'
 ←[36m2013-04-17T21:47:59.419753+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Exiting
 ←[36m2013-04-17T21:48:00.637162+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Process exited with status 1
 ←[36m2013-04-17T21:48:00.653135+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed from starting to crashed
 ←[36m2013-04-17T21:48:04.188831+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Error R12 (Exit timeout) -> At least one process failed to exit within 10 seconds of SIGTERM
 ←[36m2013-04-17T21:48:04.188831+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Stopping remaining processes with SIGKILL
 ←[36m2013-04-17T21:48:06.652384+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Process exited with status 137
 ←[33m2013-04-17T21:49:24.968073+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=nameless-peak-6062.herokuapp.com fwd="142.151.192.92" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
 ←[33m2013-04-17T21:49:25.931067+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=nameless-peak-6062.herokuapp.com fwd="142.151.192.92" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
 ←[33m2013-04-17T21:49:26.628879+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=nameless-peak-6062.herokuapp.com fwd="142.151.192.92" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
 ←[33m2013-04-17T21:49:27.165454+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=nameless-peak-6062.herokuapp.com fwd="142.151.192.92" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
 ←[33m2013-04-17T21:49:27.135930+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=nameless-peak-6062.herokuapp.com fwd="142.151.192.92" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
 ←[33m2013-04-17T21:49:30.949503+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=nameless-peak-6062.herokuapp.com fwd="142.151.192.92" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
 ←[32m2013-04-17T21:56:36.018416+00:00 heroku[slugc]:←[0m Slug compilation started
 ←[35m2013-04-17T21:57:33.471063+00:00 heroku[api]:←[0m Release v10 created by john.yeung628@gmail.com
 ←[35m2013-04-17T21:57:33.549837+00:00 heroku[api]:←[0m Deploy bf28903 by john.yeung628@gmail.com
 ←[36m2013-04-17T21:57:33.644790+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed from crashed to starting
 ←[32m2013-04-17T21:57:34.367363+00:00 heroku[slugc]:←[0m Slug compilation finished
 ←[36m2013-04-17T21:57:35.689891+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server thin -p 16004 -e $RACK_ENV`
 ←[36m2013-04-17T21:57:37.504415+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- thin (LoadError)
 ←[36m2013-04-17T21:57:37.504415+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `const_get'
 ←[36m2013-04-17T21:57:37.504415+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:272:in `server'
 ←[36m2013-04-17T21:57:37.504415+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:59:in `start'
 ←[36m2013-04-17T21:57:37.504825+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
 ←[36m2013-04-17T21:57:37.504415+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
 ←[36m2013-04-17T21:57:37.504825+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
 ←[36m2013-04-17T21:57:37.504825+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
 ←[36m2013-04-17T21:57:37.504415+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `block in get'
 ←[36m2013-04-17T21:57:37.504415+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `get'
 ←[36m2013-04-17T21:57:37.504415+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
 ←[36m2013-04-17T21:57:37.504825+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   from script/rails:6:in `require'
 ←[36m2013-04-17T21:57:37.504415+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `each'
 ←[36m2013-04-17T21:57:37.504415+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `inject'
 ←[36m2013-04-17T21:57:37.509475+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Exiting
```

Comment: Your stacktrace is very poorly formatted. Please improve the formatting.

Comment: I've improved the formatting myself this time. Next time, please double check the output and make sure it's readable when posting a question. Thank you.

Comment: sorry that was my first question and i was pretty confused with the layouts. i'll make it better for sure for next time

Answer (score 2):

That is quite the indecipherable mess.  But as far as I can tell the line that really tells the problem appears to be this:

```
9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:1:in `require': cannot load such fi
le -- thin (LoadError)
```

Have you added `thin` to the `:production` group in your `Gemfile`?

```
group :production do
  gem 'thin'
end
```

Comment: I tidied it up for you. You're right that he's missing thin.

Comment: i added the above code in gemfile, but the problem persists

Comment: there's this "ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished (ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished):" line in the logs

Answer (score 0):

Add to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'thin'
```

Answer (score 0):

so after installing gem 'thin', there was still a problem. apparently my `config.assets.compile` was set to false 
in config/environments/production.rb 
Now it's working :)
thanks a lot everyone!

Comment: Hrmm... shouldn't the assets be pre-compiled during a deploy to heroku?  I have `config.assets.compile` set to false intentionally in our app.  Dynamically compiling those assets everytime a page is requested is no bueno!  Do you get an error when you set that to `false`?  Does the heroku deploy itself give you an error?  (It should say something about precompiling assets, does that step cause any issues?)